# Optimal way to find points within polygon in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0, postgis-2.2, postgis-1.5

I've developed a query to find points which completely fall inside a polygon by using PostgreSQL 10 and PostGIS 2.4 database. The query took a long time (aprx 90mins) to produce the result. The number of records in the point table is 1,7978034. The number of records in the polygon table is 3130284. The query is:

```
select point_geom from "survey_point" where ST_Within(point_geom,(select ST_SetSRID(ST_BUFFER(st_extent(polygon_geom)::geometry,2),4326) from "parcel_polygon" where "parcel_id"='634206'))
```

This sub query was written for getting the extent of one polygon with 2 meter buffer with the SRID 4326, and it gives the result in 32ms:

```
select ST_SetSRID(ST_BUFFER(st_extent(polygon_geom)::geometry,2),4326) from "parcel_polygon" where "parcel_id"='634206'
```

But at that same time, I have taken the above sub query result as text and applied in the main query as given below, it gives the result in 72ms:

```
select point_geom  from "survey_point" where ST_Within(point_geom,ST_BUFFER(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((334094.292130328 5836905.04292025,334094.292130328 5837221.59210733,335200.835864321 5837221.59210733,335200.835864321 5836905.04292025,334094.292130328 5836905.04292025))',4326),2))
```

Is there anything wrong when applying the sub query? Are there any alternative method to do this in PostGIS?

Comment: these coordinates are not in 4326.

Comment: The query does not do what you describe. It takes a polygon, get the extent (rectangular box around it) and buffers it. You said you want the points that are inside the polygon. With this query, you can get points that are far away from the polygon.

Comment: How? ST_Within (small circle, big circle) know? So here ST_Within (point,Polygon).

Comment: The problem is that you have ST_Buffer in either a subselect or in the WHERE clause. This prevents the optimizer from using the spatial index. Either buffer everything you need in an initial CTE or create an expression index on ST_Buffer(geom), if you are going to use that a lot. If you look at EXPLAIN you can usually see these problems.